# Python QtNetwork - Download files threaded

Tags: python, download, pyqt4, qthread, qtnetwork

So I'm using `QNetworkAccessManager` (and of course `NetworkReply` and `Request`) to do some downloads. I can get this working totally fine when it's not threaded at all - and blocks the application, however no matter what method I try to use to get this to run in a non-blocking manner, it just won't work.

It seems the `.get()` from the `NetworkAccessManager` gets called, but either never connects, or never sends signals to do any writing.

If you are wondering why certain parts of the code are set up the way that they are, it was to allow easier changing around to attempt a bunch of different methods.

One thing I read on SO was to try using `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, CALL)` on some signal emits to send control back to the main event loop - I tried this to no avail though.

```
from PyQt4 import QtNetwork, QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import os


class Downloader(QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager):
    def __init__(self, url, dest):
        super(Downloader, self).__init__(None)

        self.get_path = url
        self.url = QtCore.QUrl(url)
        self.download_buffer = QtCore.QByteArray()

        self.dest = self.set_up_destination(dest)

        # self.request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(self.url)
        # self.reply = self.get(self.request)
        #
        # self.reply.readyRead.connect(self.read_data)

        self.finished.connect(self.write_finished)
        print 'Downloader Inited'

    def startDownload(self):
        self.request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(self.url)
        self.reply = self.get(self.request)

        self.reply.readyRead.connect(self.read_data)

    def set_up_destination(self, dest):
        if '.' in dest:
            dir_dest = os.path.dirname(dest)
            if not os.path.isdir(dir_dest):
                os.makedirs(dir_dest)
            return dest
        else:
            if not os.path.isdir(dest):
                os.makedirs(dest)
            base = os.path.basename(self.get_path)
            return os.path.join(dest, base).replace('\\', '/')

    def write_finished(self):
        write_file = QtCore.QFile(self.dest)
        if write_file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly):
            write_file.write(self.download_buffer)
            write_file.close()
            print 'Wrote File: {0}'.format(os.path.basename(self.dest))
        else:
            print 'ERROR'

    def read_data(self):
        self.download_buffer += self.reply.readAll()

    def print_progress(self, gotten, total):
        gotten = gotten/float(1000000)
        total = total/float(1000000)

        self.total = total
        divisor = total/5.0
        if gotten > (divisor*self.notify_count):
            self.notify_count += 1
            print 'Downloaded {0}/{1} Mb'.format(gotten, total)
        else:
            pass


class DownloadForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, from_dir, to_dir):
        super(DownloadForm, self).__init__(None)

        self.from_dir = from_dir
        self.to_dir = to_dir

        self.downloaders = []

        self.run_count = 0
        self.done_count = 0
        self.display_label = QtGui.QLabel('Downloading items...')

        self.vlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.display_label)
        self.setLayout(self.vlayout)

        self.start_downloads(self.from_dir, self.to_dir)

    def start_downloads(self, from_dir, to_dir):
        items = os.path.listdir(from_dir)
        items = [os.path.join(from_dir, x) for x in items]


        self.run_count = len(items)
        self.display_label.setText('Downloading {0} items...'.format(self.run_count))

        for item in items:
            print 'starting item: {0}'.format(os.path.basename(from_dir))
            m = Downloader(item, to_dir)
            m.finished.connect(self.adjust_run_count)
            self.downloaders.append(m)

        for item in self.downloaders:
            item.startDownload()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(object)
    def adjust_run_count(self, v):
        self.done_count += 1
        if self.done_count >= self.run_count:
            self.display_label.setText('All Items Finished!')


class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        super(Thread, self).__init__(None)

        self.lst = lst

    def run(self):
        for item in self.lst:
            item.startDownload()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    DIR1 = None #Give it a path to a folder containing some files
    DIR2 = None #Give it a path to an empty folder to 'copy' to.
    form = DownloadForm('DIR1',
                        'DIR2')
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

It's set up to run locally for now just to get this to work.

This was my latest attempt (that I figured wouldn't work, but I saw a post similar to this somewhere the other day so I figured I'd exhaust any resources before coming here - this one is really bad!!!)

I have tried things such as:
Created a thread (as a child of the GUI) that actually made each Manager object, stored a var on how many managers it made (ex, 50) connected their finish signal to its own slot that would increment a `finished_count` var until it hit 50 (meaning they are all done) which would then emit its own signal, or print 'done' or something.

Making separate threads per job in a similar signal/slot manner

You all get the idea, there were a few other methods I tried - the things they all have in common:
- Involved `QThreads`
- Either A) Don't work, or B (more likely) Work, and I'm doing it wrong.

I'm a bit at a loss here.
Hope someone can help!